# SSL: Page Includes Resources Which are not Secure

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2003, security, ssl

I get this error every time I have a request to my SSL server, even when it's a text file. Is it not sending the response via SSL?

Apache SSL config:

```
Listen 443

AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl

SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

SSLMutex default

<VirtualHost _default_:443>

DocumentRoot "C:/Websites/xivio.com"
ServerName ww6.xivio.com:443
ServerAdmin admin@xivio.com
ErrorLog "C:/error.log"
TransferLog "C:/access.log"
Redirect permanent /bftq5/index.cfm http://www.xivio.com/www/index.cfm
Redirect permanent /index.cfm http://www.xivio.com/www/index.cfm
Redirect permanent /undefined http://www.xivio.com/t.txt

SSLEngine on

SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL

SSLCertificateFile "C:/ww6_xivio_com.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/myserver.key"

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

CustomLog "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

You can see my [robots.txt](https://ww6.xivio.com/robots.txt) file has this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your error is in a browser then this usually means that a resource or asset on the SSL page is being loaded up using HTTP rather than HTTPS. This can be an image, a third party counter widget or anything. If you check your images are relative links (`../images/image1.jpg`) and not absolute (`http://me.com/images/image1.jpg`) that's usually a good starting point.

--edit--
Even with a text file the quickest way to debug this might be to `View Source` of the page throwing up the error in your browser and see what's actually being sent to the browser.

Comment: View source just shows the contents of the text file, I'm trying to read a text file just to show that there are no external resources being loaded but that text file.

Comment: That's a good way of eliminating a few things. I'd go back the additions you made to the default Apache SSL config file 'diff -y oldile newfile' to compare what might cause it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your SSLCertificateKeyFile entry is missing from your configuration.  It's also possible that your certificate was signed with an intermediate certificate that you may also need to include with a SSLCertificateChainFile directive.

Comment: It's there, I just missed putting it in when I removed all the comments to make it shorter.

Comment: OK.  The site name is www.xivio.com?  Connecting to it with openssl indicates that the peer certificate is not trusted.  Did your CA provide an Intermediate certificate or two to go along with the certificate you purchased?

Comment: It's ww6.xivio.com, try https://ww6.xivio.com/robots.txt

Comment: There's another question, how can I make it not freak out when you go to the https www instead of https ww6? Can I have it redirect? Also, I found out that it is working with the robots txt, it's just that once you are in chrome and you have a non-htttps, it never has a check mark on that tab again.

Comment: If you purchased a cert with multiple SAN entries and one of them is ww6.xivio.com, then you're all set.  But if the cert was only purchased for common name "ww6.xivio.com", you're kind of stuck until you replace the cert.  You'd also need to alias www.xivio.com to ww6.xivio.com in your dns.